# Can't write in a file with PrintWriter

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, printwriter

I want to write in my file dir.txt.
It works in Eclipse, but when I export the project as a runnable JAR File, the `PrintWriter` doesn't find the file (`FileNotFoundException`).

I use this :

```
public static final String DIR_PATH = "temp/dir.txt";
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(DIR_PATH));
```

I use a `BufferedReader` on the same file and it didn't work too, but I fixed it be doing this

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(DIR_PATH)));
```

Can I do the same thing with `PrintWriter`?

My project in the Package Explorer

[image]

Comment: try `/temp/dir.txt`

Comment: @YassinHajaj if I do that, my BufferedReader now doesn't work in Eclipse

Comment: YourClass.class.getResource("/your_root_package/temp/dir.txt");

Comment: I noticed that my PrintWriter isn even working in Eclipse...the path i have to use is src/temp/dir.txt, that's why it's not working in a .jar, because ther is no /src when export.

Comment: @manikantgautam "The constructor PrintWriter(URL) is undefined"

Answer (score 1):

A .jar archive should be readable-only, so you can't as well writing on a .txt file which is inside the .jar file.

But you can have the .txt file outside the .jar and use "./temp/dir.txt" to write in it.

Comment: Oh I see. I probably have to do that. ;)